# Lift Session Issue with Basic Authentication

Tags: httpwebrequest, lift

I have two application written in lift with embedded jetty. The first one is maintaining session based on `SessionVar` implementation. And that is working great without any problem.
In second application I am using `Basic Authentication`, which is also working great.

The problem arises when I open both applications in the same browser in different tabs. Even though both applications are running on different ports, the second application causes first to session out.

**Does any one have got any idea what's the problem is and how do I resolve this issue?**

I am using scala 2.9.0.1 and lift 2.4-M1.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP port does not affect session management at all. The web server will see them as the same thing. If you want to run them both concurrently, perhaps try accessing one at 127.0.0.1 and the other at localhost, thus negating the issue of them being on the same perceived host.

FWIW, LiftSession is not instantiated at the time of basic authentication; i'm pretty sure its cached by the browser and not by Lift.